# Solving this random variable problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

This is an earlier problem [Proving this random variable problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798072/proving-this-random-variable-problem) but generalised, maybe you want to take a look at that one first?

$X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are IID random variable taking values in $(-1,\infty)$.

Also $t\in(0,1)$.

$f_1>0$ is a positive constant and $f_2,f_3,f_4\ldots$ are positive functions of one variable.

Define random variables $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\ldots$ recursively like

$$Y_1 = (1+tX_1) - f_1$$
$$Y_n = Y_{n-1}(1+tX_n) - f_n(Y_{n-1})$$

Imagine this is money being partially invested someplace again and again with transaction fee each time (dependent on the current money amount).

Can I prove that

$$Y_n\to\infty\,\, \textrm{a.s.}\,\,\,\,\textrm{if and only if}\,\,\,\, E[\log(1+tX_1)] > 0 \,\,\,\,\,\textrm{}$$

given some reasonable conditions on the $f$'s? If so, what are those conditions?

Comment: Assuming my answer to your first question is on the right track, one guess is that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(Y_{n-1})=0$, you have the same result. For that to work, it would of course also be necessary for $Y_j$ to be positive for $j=1, 2, ...$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one set of conditions.

> Assume that $f_1\leqslant1-t$ and that, for every $n\geqslant2$, there exists some $a_n\leqslant1-t$ such that $f_n(x)\leqslant a_nx$ for every $x\geqslant0$. Consider $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$ and assume that $E(\log(1+tX_1-a))\gt0$ (note that $1+tX_1\gt a$ almost surely).
>
> Then $Y_n\to+\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Is it also true that if $E(log(1+tX1−a))<0$ then $Y_n\to 0$? If not, it would be nice to find such a "wall of separation" or the "breaking point" where $Y_n$ starts to approach 0 instead of $\infty$. Otherwise this choice of condition would seem a bit arbitrary... do you have ideas?

Comment: No hope, try alternating the functions $f_n$ between two linear functions $g(x)=bx$ and $h(x)=cx$.

Comment: But what about multiple conditions? Could we say that $E[log(1+tX_i)-f_i]>0$ for all $i$ implies $Y_n\to\infty$ and $E[log(1+tX_i)-f_i]<0$ for all $i$ implies $Y_n\to0$ ? If so (or something similar), how could we prove this?

Comment: Applying the SLLN as in the answer to your other question. Show me...

Comment: You mean multiple conditions would be possible? 
 
I don't see similarities with the other problem, because of the $f_i$ I can't write $Y_n$ as one product or $\log(Y_n)$ as a sum of logs so it looks different?

Comment: I have reformulated the problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800726/dealing-with-this-random-variable-problem