# Dealing with this random variable problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

$X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are IID random variable taking values in $(-1,\infty)$.

Also $t\in(0,1)$.

$f_1>0$ is a positive constant and $f_2,f_3,f_4\ldots$ are positive functions of one variable.

Define random variables $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\ldots$ recursively like

$$Y_1 = (1+tX_1) - f_1$$
$$Y_n = Y_{n-1}(1+tX_n) - f_n(Y_{n-1})$$

Imagine money being partially invested someplace again and again with transaction fee each time (dependent on the current money amount).

Can I prove this or something similar to

---

$$Y_n\to\infty\,\, \textrm{a.s.}\,\,\,\,\textrm{if}\,\,\,\, E[\log(1+tX_1-f_i)] > 0\textrm{ for all $i$} \,\,\,\,\,\textrm{}$$

**and**

$$Y_n\to 0\,\, \textrm{a.s.}\,\,\,\,\textrm{if}\,\,\,\, E[\log(1+tX_1-f_i)] < 0\textrm{ for all $i$} \,\,\,\,\,\textrm{}$$

---

given some reasonable conditions on the $f$'s? If so, how to prove it and what are those conditions?

If this is possible I imagine those expectations would have to be **conditional expectations** since the $f_n$s depend on $Y_{n-1}$s, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: I am surprised: I thought the approach I explained on your other question was giving simple versions of these results.

Comment: The approach I explained can be adapted to the present situation (but it is quite true that I did not post a detailed explanation of this adaptation, I was somehow expecting that you would try to start the job yourself).

Comment: ok think i get it now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need another condition on your functions $f_i$, because for example they may map very small values to $10$ and still result in negative expectation in your proposed condition. Perhaps your functions need to be increasing.